# Vector menu tools missing (processing plugin broken)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, vector, error, qgis-processing

All of a sudden my vector menu tools are missing. I know this is a common bug but all the instructions on how to fix it didn't work for me.

I checked if the processing plugin is installed but QGIS tells me this plugin is broken.

I tried uninstalling it and deleted the .qgis2 folder but even after reinstalling nothing changed.

I'm using QGIS version 2.18.2 on macOS Sierra.

[image]

Comment: A full re-install might be easiest.

Comment: I did uninstall and reinstall it. Do I have to delete anything else besides the application and the .qgis2 folder?

Comment: .qgis2 folder should be enough. Are you using the Kyngchaos installer? http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Comment: Yes I'm using Kyngchaos

Comment: Is there anything in your \.qgis2\python\plugins folder? QGIS reported processing as broken directly after the reinstall of QGIS?

Comment: Are other python plugins running ok? Otherwise python support may be broken.

Comment: There is only one folder in the plugins folder called "MetaSearch" and yes QGIS reports broken directly after the reinstall with this error message: "Python error: Couldn't load plugin processing due to an error when calling its classFactory() method See message log (Python Error) for more details."

Other python plugins are running okay!

Comment: I found the "Processing" folder in this location: "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/plugins" and copied it to "/.qgis2/python/plugins" but that doesn't change anything either...

Comment: Can you try: https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/203#issuecomment-276541008

Comment: Thanks! It definitely had to do with the file that is mentioned in your link, but I just removed it completely and reinstalled QGIS (see my answer below). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the files that were still left on the computer! So I followed this instruction:

https://www.uninstallmacapp.com/quantum-gis-2-8-1-removal.html

"3. Remove all components related to Quantum GIS 2.8.1 in Finder"
I only found the remaining files when I used the "Go to folder" function in the Finder. Like in the figure I typed in "~/Library" (there is different Library folders on Mac but the "Go to folder" directed me to the right one)

Under "Preferences" I found and deleted this: "org.qgis.QGIS2.plist"
I believe there was another file with a similar name in the "Application Support" or "Caches" folder but I can't find it anymore now. I deleted both those files, the .qgis2 folder, and the Application, emptied the trash and reinstalled QGIS. When starting it again there were no more errors and the Vector menu reappeared!

Hope this might help people who are confronted with the same problem! Thanks everyone for the help!